# how to convert logits to probability in binary classification in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

```
logits= tf.matmul(inputs, weight) + bias
```

After matmul operation, the logits are two values derive from the MLP layer. 
My target is binary classification, how to convert the two values, logits, into probabilities, which include positive prob and negative prob and the sum of them is 1 ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
predictions = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
```

Comment: This is not the way to go. If you have only one label, which is true (1) or false (0), this will result in a prediction probability of 1 for all samples -- no what you want

Comment: @emem that's not true. If your last layer output logit that have value `< 0` for `class 0` and `> 0` for `class 1`, for example your last layer is `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)` and using loss function `losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)`, you need to add `tf.nn.softmax(logit)` layer after the train to convert the logit into a meaningful probability that can be interpreted by human.

Comment: @MuhammadYasirroni I was referring to a single value output, you are talking about two outputs. See the answer by Suleka_28, this is the correct answer

Answer (score 46):

I am writing this answer for anyone who needs further clarifications:

If it is a binary classification, it should be:

```
prediction = tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid(logit))
```

If it is a multi-class classification:

```
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logit)
```

then using the argmax function you can get the index of the class that has the highest probability score.

```
np.argmax(prediction, 0)
```

Comment: Note that you can also run `np.argmax` directly on logits.

Comment: For binary classification, why is `tf.nn.sigmoid` necessary to decide the positive/negative classes? when `logit > 0, then probability > 0.5`, thus positive class; vice versa. the `tf.round(tf.nn.sigmoid())` function call is unnecessary.

Comment: @thinkdeep if the model return raw `logit` (positive and negative value), the `tf.nn.sigmoid(logit)` will convert the value between `0-1`, with the negative value converted to `0-0.5`, positive value to `0.5-1`, and zero to `0.5`, or you can call it probability. After that, `tf.round(probability)` will use `0.5` as the threshold for rounding to `0` or `1`. This is because lots of labels outside there use `class 0` and `class 1` label. It's just another way to convey positive logit as positive class and vice versa.